# Is it possible to enable dwm dynamically with code?

Tags: winapi, dwm

DwmEnableComposition cannot enable composition system wide. If I want to enable the aero effect system wide, how could I do this with c/c++ code?

Comment: `DwmEnableComposition()`can no longer disable DWM starting in Windows 8. AFAIK, Aero can only be affected by the user via the Control Panel, not in code.  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: just for test dwm on my application.

Comment: This doesn't explain, why you need to enable/disable DWM system-wide through code. Enable/Disable it through the control panel and test your application.